# Creating a bridge for Xen

Tags: bridge

I am currently stucking at creating a bridge for Xen. My current interface file looks like this:

```
      auto lo
      iface lo inet loopback

      auto eth0
      iface eth0 inet static
                address 81.30.152.XX
                netmask 255.255.255.0
                broadcast 81.30.152.255
                gateway 81.30.152.1

      auto xenbr0
      iface xenbr0 inet static
                address 81.30.152.XX
                netmask 255.255.255.0
                broadcast 81.30.152.255
                gateway 81.30.152.1
                bridge_ports eth0
                bridge_fd 9
                bridge_hello 2
                bridge_maxage 12
                bridge_stp off
```

But xenbr0 doesn't apprear in ifconfig, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st step Edit /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp and find the "(network-script network-bridge)" line, comment it out, and replace it with a call to your own wrapper script "(network-script network-multi-bridge)". In /etc/xen/scripts/ called "network-multi-bridge", which will call the network-bridge script twice, once for each interface.

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=$(dirname "$0")
"$dir/network-bridge" "$@" vifnum=0 bridge=xenbr0 netdev=eth0  
"$dir/network-bridge" "$@" vifnum=1 bridge=xenbr1 netdev=eth1

# chmod +x /etc/xen/scripts/network-multi-bridge

# service network restart

# ifconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: 
1. Remove the eth0 block entirely 
2. Add the bridge for eth0 (xenbr0 runs "over" eth0)

> auto xenbr0 
>   iface xenbr0 inet static 
>                  address 81.30.152.XX(Use the IP you need for your Dom0) 
>  
>                  netmask 255.255.255.0 
>                  broadcast 81.30.152.255 
>                  gateway 81.30.152.1 
>                  bridge_ports eth0 
>                  bridge_fd 9 
>                  bridge_hello 2 
>                  bridge_maxage 12 
>                  bridge_stp off